# How to get timestamp pieces from raw PG value in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, timestamp

If I log a timestamp in a NodeJS app, which I'm trying to split out of PG I can see:
"2020-01-01T11:58:00.000Z"
If I attempt to overcome a situation where I cannot split that where the error is *.split is not a function.* by doing either `<varname> + ''`, or `<varname>.toString()` I get:
Wed Jan 01 2020 05:58:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)

While I can still get to the numbers I'm seeking doing things that way I strongly feel there has to be a better way!? I can wrap the value in `new Date(<varname>)` and use `getMinutes()` and `getSeconds()` I get the correct value. However, using `getHours()` returns a 5 for the aforementioned datetime value.

I THOUGHT doing the following would suffice to get all the parts I wanted, but again, *split is not a function*:

```
const pieces = prevavg[0]['event_datetime'].split('T')[1].split('.')[0].split(':').map(x => parseInt(x));
const [hours, minutes, seconds] = pieces;
```

What is the optimal way to simply (you'd think) get the [11, 58, 0] out of the db timestamp in JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp is in UTC (since it ends with 'Z'), but `getHours` returns the hours in your local time zone. You should use `getUTCHours` (and `getUTCMinutes` and `getUTCSeconds`) instead.

Comment: That did it. I can finally just work with the datetime out of the Db now. No need to wrap it in `new Date(<varname>)`. Just straight up `dbValue.getUTCHours()`, etc. I've no idea why somebody would downvote this. I didn't know so somebody else won't either!